# IONIC Cant build android --prod, because of Broken @import declaration of

Tags: android, css, ionic3

I cant build on --prod mode, the error was

[image]

Those files are exists

[image]

the normal build was fine, but with --prod i cant build the apk. Anyone can help?

-----SOLVED----------------------------------
okay this is solved by adding `options: {processImport: false} on node_module\@ionic\app-scripts\config\cleancss.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution, but this way you wont loose anything after update @ionic/app-scripts:

insert into **package.json** file:

```
{
  {... other configs....},

 "config": {
        "ionic_cleancss": "./config/cleancss.config.js"
    }
}
```

create the file **./config/cleancss.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  options: {processImport: false}
};
```